# In a React,Redux app I want to calculate a subtotal (price * qtyCount) for each object in an array of objects using a selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I edited my question and added the component in question.
I suspect maybe just me not understanding the syntax.

My current output in component looks like this `25.0018.00` it should be `25.00` for 1 object and `18.00` for next.

I have an array of objects that look like this:

**Json:**

```
counters: [
    {
      id: "lam1g8uzn",
      windowType: "First ",
      windowLocation: "Out",
      price: 5,
      qtyCount: 5,
      imgUrl:'long string'
    },
    {
      id: "r5hamynf3",
      windowType: "Second ",
      windowLocation: "In",
      price: 2,
      qtyCount: 9,
      imgUrl: 'long string'
    }
]
```

**Here is my selector**

```
  const selectCounter = (state) => state.counter;

  export const selectCounterItems = createSelector(
   [selectCounter],
   (counter) => counter.counters,
  );
```

**This is the selector in question**

```
  export const selectCounterSubtotal = createSelector(
      [selectCounterItems],
      (counters) => counters.map((counter) => (
      (counter.qtyCount * counter.price).toFixed(2)
    )),
  );
```

**Here is  my component where subtotal is displayed**

```
 import { connect } from 'react-redux';
 import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
 import { selectCounterSubtotal } from '../../redux/counter/counter- 
 selectors';

 const SubTotalDisplay = ({ subTotal }) => (
  // const subtotal = (qty * price).toFixed(2);
  <div className="subtotal-diaplay">
  <span> Subtotal $</span>
  <span className="subtotal">{subTotal}</span>
  </div>
 );

 const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  subTotal: selectCounterSubtotal,
 });

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(SubTotalDisplay);
```

Comment: is it just that the numbers are right next to each other?
I think we need to see your html?

Comment: looks like the `createSelector` function returns a single value, instead of an array as you need. If you see, it is doing the multiplication, but is returning them together concatenated as a single value. I believe it doesn't fit for your case. Try using it outside the `createSelector` function and check if works.

Comment: My whole problem is when I calculate the subtotal locally in component it's not updating until I refresh, so that is why I thought about using selector

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an array of strings to `SubtotalDisplay`. When React gets an array node it renders each of the items in the array. That's why you're getting "25.0018.00".

Consider updating the `SubtotalDisplay` component to render all subtotals passed to it:

```
const SubTotalDisplay = ({ subTotals }) => (
  subTotals.map((subTotal, index) => (
    <div className="subtotal-display" key={index}>
      <span> Subtotal $</span>
      <span className="subtotal">{subTotal}</span>
    </div>
  ))
);

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  subTotals: selectCounterSubtotal,
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Corey I understand that I think I am just taking the wrong approach. When I calculate the subtotal locally(not using the selector) in the SubTotal Component it works fine except when I fire my reset all counters function the subtotal does not update.

Comment: Thanks to all after banging around a bit I figured out this was the wrong approach to take. The solution I discovered is I was mutating my data when invoking my reset function, just need to  clone the object.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my problem was actually in another utility function where I was mistakenly mutating data.

```
//Right Way    
export const resetAllCounters = (counters) => counters.map((counter) => ({ 
       ...counter, qtyCount: 0 }));

// Wrong way mutating data
export const resetAllCounters = (counters) => counters.map((counter) => 
Object.assign(counter, { qtyCount: 0 }));
```

Comment: Voting to close on account of this largely being a result of a different problem (i.e. unlikely to help future readers).

Comment: @coreyward Thanks, Again I would also vote to close. What I learned the most about this is to ask better questions